# Trouble connectiong to SQL Server Express 2008 remotely with C# - But Windows ODBC administrator works

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm having trouble connecting to the server with C# using Windows Authentication.  Using the

Using the MS ODBC Data Source Administrator on a remote computer, I do the following steps:

1. Create new data source using SQL Server Native Client 11.0.
2. Enter a name for my connection and add the server/instance to the server, click next
3. Select *With Windows Integrated authentication.* leave *SPN(Optional)* blank and click next
4. Check *Change the default database to* and click the drop down to select the database, it lists the databases as it should because the connection worked.

When I try to connect using my C# application:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

When I try to use the application on the machine with the sql server, it connects fine.

Here's the simple connection code:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=servername\\instancename;Initial Catalog=databasename;Integrated Security=SSPI;");
conn.Open();
```

servername, instancename, and databasename are all correct.  Enabled tcp/ip, named pipes, remote connection (remember, the ODBC administrator connects without issue), but just can't get my app to connect.  Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've figured it out.  The server is a 32 bit server and I had VS2012 compiling to Any CPU.  Changed it to x86 and it works perfectly.

Comment: Mark this as the Answer by selecting the checkmark next to the up/down arrows. Good job finding the solution!